# Can I use raw socket or libcurl to access Http resource for App Transport Security?

Tags: ios, https, app-transport-security

It is known that apple will enforce Https access across iOS system 2017 jan. It is possible use raw socket or 3rd party network library like libcurl to access Http resource?

Comment: You can still disable ATS, you just need to provide details in your review notes as to why

Comment: Does ATS only affect iOS native API or framework?

Comment: I don't know what happens if you use a low level socket to open a connection on port 80. I suspect it will work, but it is a lot of work to implement your own http client for no reason

Comment: Actually I have been using libcurl to work with Http for multi-platform apps, so it is very common to use raw socket

Comment: you could try libcurl, but it is still much easier to use the frameworks that iOS provides